# Maintaining Similar URL for Multiple Methods Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a 3 controllers with the method show namely

```
class CarController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end
end

class MotorcycleController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end
end

class TravelController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end
end
```

In my routes, i want the show method of all tree to follow the same url structure `/:company_id/:id`

So given an example that my home page url is `https://localhost:3000`, company id is `1` and id is `2`, if i go to the show method of car controller, my url should be `http://localhost:3000/1/2`

At the moment, i did this in my routes

```
get '/:company_id/:id' => 'travel_controller#show', as: 'travel_insurance_product'
    get '/:company_id/:id' => 'car_controller#show', as: 'car_insurance_product'
    get '/:company_id/:id' => 'motorcycle_controller#show', as: 'motorcycle_insurance_product'
```

But when i trigger the car show method, it goes to the travel controller method

Is this possible to be done in ruby?

Comment: What do you mean with "when I trigger the car show method"? you enter an URL (/1/2), rails parses it, and, at the first match, it calls the controller's action. I don't think you are understanding the request's lifecycle.

Comment: How would you access `MotorcycleController#show` and `TravelController#show`? What would be the URL for those?

Comment: Your question includes an example (`/1/2`) that should route to the `CarController`. Please elaborate and add examples for routes that should route to the `TravelController` and the `MotorcycleController` and explain how you (as a human) would decide which controller to route to just by looking at the ids - where to route for example `/12/12` or `/47/999`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. How is the router supposed to know if the `id` is for a `Car`, `Motorcycle`, or `Travel`?

BTW, the convention is for the controller to be in the plural form (such as `MotorcyclesController`).

Also BTW, routing is a Rails phenomenon, not a Ruby phenomenon.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The OP asked whether it is possible to route calls such a `http://localhost:3000/1/2` and `http://localhost:3000/2/5` to different controllers and I answered "No". That seems like an answer to me. But, I appreciate the comment.